# makefile : commands commence before first target

Tags: c

I created a .so file and have a .c file which uses functions from this .so.

The way I create my .so :

```
 gcc -shared -fPIC -o my_malloc.so my_malloc.c -ldl
```

The way I compiled my .c file which is using .so :

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.o ./my_malloc.so
```

And then I run the program using:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so ./hello.o
```

Now I want to create a makefile to do all these steps:

```
#Compiler to use
CC=gcc

#different flags
CFLAGS= -c -Wall

all: malloc_profiler
malloc_profiler : LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so ./hello.o
    $(CC) my_malloc.so hello.o -o malloc_profiler

my_malloc.so : my_malloc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o my_malloc.so my_malloc.c -ldl

hello.o : hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello.o ./my_malloc.so

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I am getting following error.

```
make all
makefile:10: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the command line you used to **run** the program as list of prerequisites in the Makefile and then you call the compiler:

```
malloc_profiler : LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so ./hello.o
    $(CC) my_malloc.so hello.o -o malloc_profiler
```

Change this into a correct list and call your program:

```
malloc_profiler : my_malloc.so hello.o
    LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so ./hello.o
```

Additionally your CFLAGS include the `-c` option which you don't have on your original command lines.

To test your Makefile without running the commands call it like this:

```
make -nB
```